# Openshift: Jenkins in a separate project

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-origin

I read and watched many tutorials about using Jenkins in Openshift. In all these tutorials the application has been deployed inside the same project with Jenkins.

Is it possible in Openshift to have only one Jenkins instance in a separate project and use it in other projects?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by adding **Role-Based Access Controls**, granting the Jenkins service account access to the project.

```
 oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:cicd:jenkins -n <project_name>
```

If you need more help the free e-book "DevOps with OpenShift" is a good one.  It covers the requested details in Chapter 4.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's recommended to have a CI/CD project with Jenkins and a separate one with your app.
Tutorial: https://youtu.be/tUqwKQsHLkY

Comment: Veer I think his name is?  His video helped me out, thats his second one but the first one is helpful to watch as well, once you get the first video watched and pipeline working then based on the second https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07-Xx73y3zA video it all becomes clear.